# How can i limit the number of rows a user can update?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

One of our Business Research Analysts has a habit of accidentally updating without a where clause. 
Preferably the solution is better training and following a procedure like writing a SELECT before UPDATE. Or just security policies...

However, those things aren't going to happen soon. So I would also like to know if there is a way to limit a user to only being able to update X number of rows. i.e if they run an update that will do 10 rows, let it go. If it will be 1 millions rows (happened the other day) prompt them to double check or just stop that query.

Comment: Assuming this is a single statement, a trigger on the table could look at `inserted` and `deleted` and throw an error if too many rows are being modified.  Of course, that would mean that you'd need a trigger per table.  But, presumably, a business analyst isn't modifying data in too many tables.  Alternatively, you could give him a procedure that takes a SQL statement and executes it.  If you do that inside a transaction, you could rollback if too many rows were modified.

Comment: Block his access until he learns.

Comment: Give them a UI instead of direct SSMS access. You can control users and their actions easily. However, it will be a tedious task to build such a UI for users who can do anything. Other than TRIGGERS you can also use TRANSACTION and rollback when update count > X number. Not an efficient way but it should work